# Removing brackets in class content

Tags: python

[image: TextFile contents]
I am trying to fill different nodes with individual letters by reading them in from a text, which does work but not like I was hoping. When I try to call the attribute function of Node to get the content I am given a ['H'] instead of just H which makes comparison in a different part of the program impossible. Is there a way to remove the brackets and Just enter a single letter into the contents of each of my nodes?

```
def createLattice():
    test = []
    with open("lattice.txt", 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            items = line.split()
            test.append(items[0:])

    Node1 = Node(test[0])
    Node2 = Node(test[1])
    Node3 = Node(test[2])
    Node4 = Node(test[3])
    Node5 = Node(test[4])
    Node6 = Node(test[5])
    Node7 = Node(test[6])
    Node8 = Node(test[7])
    Node9 = Node(test[8])
    Node10 = Node(test[9])
    Node11 = Node(test[10])
    Node12 = Node(test[11])
    Node13 = Node(test[12])
    Node14 = Node(test[13])
    Node15 = Node(test[14])
    Node16 = Node(test[15])
    Node17 = Node(test[16])
    Node18 = Node(test[17])

    lattice = {Node1: [Node2, Node6, Node7],
               Node2: [Node1, Node3, Node5, Node8],
               Node3: [Node2, Node4, Node9],
               Node4: [Node3, Node5, Node10],
               Node5: [Node2, Node4, Node6, Node11],
               Node6: [Node5, Node1, Node12],
               Node7: [Node1, Node8, Node12, Node13],
               Node8: [Node2, Node7, Node9, Node12, Node14],
               Node9: [Node3, Node8, Node10, Node15],
               Node10: [Node4, Node9, Node11, Node16],
               Node11: [Node5, Node8, Node10, Node12, Node17],
               Node12: [Node6, Node7, Node11, Node18],
               Node13: [Node7, Node14, Node18],
               Node14: [Node8, Node13, Node15, Node17],
               Node15: [Node9, Node14, Node16],
               Node16: [Node10, Node15, Node17],
               Node17: [Node11, Node14, Node16, Node18],
               Node18: [Node12, Node13, Node17]}

    return lattice
```

Comment: `test.append(items[0:])` creates a 2-dimensional list. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Barmar No, but im not sure how else to get the letter from the text file into Node 1 - 18 with appending it to another list first.

Comment: Can you show us what the text file contains, and what the resulting nodes should contain? I suspect you just want to use `items[0]` instead of `items[0:]`, but it's not clear.

Comment: Why were using using `[0:]` in the first place? That makes a copy of the list, but there's no need to make a copy since you're not using that list anywhere else.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `test` is a list of lists, instead of letters.

In this line:

```
test.append(items[0:])
```

You create a "[slice](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/)" of items, which is a list it self, and insert it in to `test`.
Note that `append` does not concatenate lists, it only adds a new item to the end of the list (even when that item is a list it self).

There are 2 ways to solve your problem:

1. Just remove the colon like this:

   test.append(items[0])

   This will make `test` a list of letters and not list of lists.
2. If you want to keep the slices for some reason, use first item of every list in `test` to initialize your `Node` objects like this:

   Node1 = Node(test[0][0])

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a misunderstanding of the [0:] removing the : fixed the problem.